# Unity3D: NullReferenceException even I have set it in Inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception

I am try to update GUI during `Update()`. Here is the code:

```
void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log(HPText == null);
        HPText.text = HP + " / " + MaxHP;
    }
```

I have already set the HPText through Inspector.
[image]

And I get the following in the console. It seems that it keep alternating between null and not null. How can I get rid of the error?
[image]

Comment: Is it possible you have more than one object running this script?

Comment: The information you have given is not enough. Include more codes from your class like how are you declaring HPText or screenshot of you project hierarchy.

Comment: @MickyDuncan Thanks, you are right. I have 2 object using the same script. I forget to disable the one I am not using.

Comment: You're quite welcome good sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

---

**Note:** This is a summary answer based on my comment above.

---

Sounds like you have more than one object running this script.  Check your scene and remove the script from the second object.  One object has the **HPText** property set, the other more than likely does not.

> *Thanks, you are right. I have 2 object using the same script. I forget to disable the one I am not using.* –  Joshua

Alternatively, you could set the **HPText** on the second object. You mentioned you have since disabled the second object - that works too.